# Search for a string with a point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

When I try to seach for a string with a point (i.e. `'1.'`), js also points to substrings with commas instead of points. It's better to look at the example:

```
'1,'.search('1.');        // 0
'xxx1,xxx'.search('1.');  // 3
// Normal behaviour
'1.'.search('1,');        // -1
```

Does anyone know why JavaScript behave itself so?
Is there a way to search for exactly passed string?

Comment: In none of your examples does the search string match the string provided. You're always trying to match `1,` against `1.` or vice versa. Anyway, use a regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

> The `search()` method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and this `String` object.

`.` has a special meaning in Regular Expressions. You need to escape the `.` before matching it. Try the following:

```js
console.log('xxx1,xxx'.search('1\\.'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**.

```js
let str = "abc1,231.4";
console.log(str.indexOf("1."));
```

Comment: Easier and faster; very appropriate for this case. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

indexOf() method should work fine in this case

```
'1,'.indexOf('1.');
```

The above code should return -1

Comment: Same answer was posted 4 minutes earlier. How is this any better?

Answer (score 0):

[String.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/search) is taking regex as parameter.

Regex evaluate `.` by `any character`; you gotta escape it using double anti-slash `\\`.

```js
console.log('1,'.search('1\\.'));

console.log('xxx1,xxx'.search('1\\.'));
console.log('xxx1.xxx'.search('1\\.'));

console.log('1.'.search('1,'));
```